# OpenGL gl_Postion in geometry shader

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader, geometry-shader

I am passing vertices from the vertex shader to the geometry shader. I am doing a perspective projection in the geometry shader. I understand that before the fragment shader, OpenGL divides the `gl_Position` vector by the `w` component. Does this happen before or after the geometry shader? If it is after, is there a quick way to do it before without manually dividing by `w` in the vertex shader?

Edit: Right now this is the end of my vertex shader.

```
gl_Position = proj*view*model*vPos;
gl_Position = (1.0/gl_Position.w)*gl_Position;
```

Answer (score 2):

> OpenGL divides the `gl_Position` vector by the `w` component.

No, it does not. It divides the clip-space position of a vertex to be rasterized by the clip-space position's `w` coordinate. The [clip-space position of a vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping) is the value of `gl_Position` emitted for that vertex from the last [vertex processing stage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Processing) before rasterization. All of the shader stages before rasterization are vertex processing stages.

A vertex processing stage which is not the last such stage can output to `gl_Position`, but this has no special meaning. The next vertex processing stage could take that as an input, but the value is passed through as is.

> If it is after, is there a quick way to do it before without manually dividing by `w` in the vertex shader?

You really shouldn't *want* to. It is perfectly reasonable to do processing on vertices in post-projection space as 4D values. You can apply rotation, translation, etc to these vertices as you see fit, and the result will still "make sense" if you do it in the correct space. You can even apply a second projection to them.

Comment: Not to forget that by manually dividing by w, perspective correct interpolation doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The reason I want to divide by `w`, is because I am using the geometry shader to turn lines into thicker lines (or quads) in screen space. The original vertices are in world space and projected on the screen. But I want the resulting quads to be of uniform thickness. If I do not divide by `w`, the ends of the quad will have differing thickness depending on how deep they are in the `z` direction.

Comment: However, I could as you say treat them as 4D vectors and see if I can optimize the math so I do not have to divide by `w`.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if that is possible to do in 4D space. I have to normalize a perpendicular vector in 2D, and that is already a non-linear operation. So if I keep `w` separate, that is even more non-linear math that I must undo before the clip-space normalization.